BCrypt does not detect changes near the end of very long passwords
I need some help to understand what is happening here. This test demonstrates the issue I'm having. I have a very long password, and I use BCrypt to hash it. I then try to verify the actual and hashed values. The problem I'm facing, is the library seems to return true on my modified password as well. The last assert is where this happens. I am removing the last 10 characters from my original password, why would BCrypt still match the hashed value?
org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4

@Test
fun thisTestFails() {
    val password = "YtWSXeKO3J_qhI7jArzsM5eSETrEfVpAutbCrNwx0yHOK9axNDvPQyUOLi-MapE4uUI2YVgOQjI-SCsAg0FmIJ8Ei1jBxpSrFEvDnZDEPc7ClLhfdr1RA5ruSr9qZvebLFXka-1Gl8TMscGbVZKHsYqveq5p7hnMYqrT"
    val passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt())
    val modified = password.dropLast(10)
    assertNotEquals(password, modified)
    assertTrue(BCrypt.checkpw(password, passwordHash))
    assertFalse(BCrypt.checkpw(modified, passwordHash)) // Fails here
}


bcrypt has a maximum of 55 bytes of input size. This is covered in the paper specifying it; read https://www.openbsd.org/papers/bcrypt-paper.pdf. As this is a cryptographic algorithm design result rather than a problem with your code, follow-up questions (about rationale &c) are probably better suited to [security.se].

But note that real world implementations typically have an even lower input size constraint (many don't guarantee correctness over 50 bytes). Also note that if this library lets you run bcrypt with inputs that are known to yield bad results, without throwing an error, it's probably time to report a bug to the maintainer because you should have been told in no uncertain measure to fix your input =)

@CharlesDuffy, you're the man. Thank you!

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Absolutely, thank you!

The comments were spot on, the library only supports a maximum of 54 bytes. This test confirms it. EQUAL=false begins at 54 bytes. Thank you to the helpers in the comments.
@Test
fun test() {
    for (n in 100 downTo 0) {
        val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
        val bytes = ByteArray(n)
        secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes)
        val password = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(bytes)

        val passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt())
        val modified = password.dropLast(1)

        val equal = BCrypt.checkpw(password, passwordHash) && BCrypt.checkpw(modified, passwordHash)
        println("BYTES=$n EQUAL=$equal")
    }
}

